# How to set ViewState value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some java script like follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=searchBar.ClientID%>').hide();
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("title", "Show SearchBar")
    $('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>')[0].value = "hiding";
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("src", "../common/images/show-icon.png");
    ViewState["showHideFlagValue"] = $('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>')[0].value;

});
```

This code is throwing error to set ViewState.

Can someone help to set the viewstate in this?

Comment: Where can I find the "ViewState"?

Comment: Why use `$('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>')[0].value`? You are targeting an `id` so only one element will be returned and as using jquery you can simply do `$('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>').val()`.

Comment: I am getting the value in that I wanted to assign that value to ViewState. Can I use ViewState like the way I mentioned in that code?

Comment: It is throwing error like ViewState is undefined

Comment: ViewState value on client site is an encoded string stored in a hidden html input element. You would not be able to use the view state in javascript in this manner. Instead use a hidden element to hold the value.

Comment: @user3356020 does my answer was helpful to you ?

Comment: No I tried this also but this did not work for me

Comment: Do one thing , open webpage in chrome browser ,the right click and choose view source . Press ctrl + F and search for "viewstate" . Check if you can find it or not ?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net VIEWSTATE will be saved as hidden field in the page  as below

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"
value="sdfsdfsadf" />
```

You can alter the value as you change for any input types

$('#__VIEWSTATE').val('ss')

This will set viewstate value as 'ss'